# Tkinter/class variable/method/widget.get() from another class issue in python 2.7

Tags: python, class, user-interface, oop, tkinter

I am attempting to write a python program that utilizes Tkinter window switching OOP classes. On the starting page, there is an entry form where the user fills in the relevant fields. After filling the form the button 'to tests' is clicked where the user can select the test after switching frame/window, and the user information entered is simultaneously saved in the specified directory as a .txt file as a result of this button running several methods in class Startpage. The problem occurs when data is received by clicking on the yes or no buttons in the test 1 page.

This page operates in a different class, yet requires a return value from method get_info() defined in the Startpage class to get the user information (filename) entered to create a second .txt file to store raw data, storing appended 'yes' or 'no' strings depending on the button clicked in test 1's GUI window.

However this file is never created since Test1 is not receiving any entry data from Startpage class/window, therefore cannot assign a filename (call the get_info() containing the widget.get() functions) for the second .txt file.

The information is obtained in by the methods in the class correctly and everything works fine. However the problem arises when Test1 asks to receive the widget.get() variables/methods from Startpage.

The error thrown is the following IndexError:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Rylan\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in     __call__
return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Users/Rylan/Documents/Python/Basel Summerintern files/code to help with question.py", line 280, in update_countyes
directory = "C:\Users\Rylan\Documents\Python\Basel Summerintern files\{}".format(self.get_t_info())
      File "C:/Users/Rylan/Documents/Python/Basel Summerintern files/code to help with        question.py", line 304, in get_t_info
        self.gettheinfo = Startpage(app, self.controller).get_info()
      File "C:/Users/Rylan/Documents/Python/Basel Summerintern files/code to help with question.py", line 170, in get_info
        str(Day) + "_" + str(Month) + "_" +

    IndexError: string index out of range
```

I am very new to OOP programming and to my knowledge this could be caused by:

- Not properly referring/calling the Startpage instance, therefore the variables are not received by the Test1, therefore calling the get_info() method results in with nothing received by the nested widget.get() functions/variables in get_info() method.

Basically, what is the reason for this IndexError and how do I fix it to get the filename created/returned from the get_info() method in class Startpage sent to/called by class Test1?

I have seen similar questions relating to class variable and method calling from a different class, however none of which consider the case for window/frame switching Tkinter applications.

Here is the simplified code below (might not seem like it) which is able to be run (you may have directory path existence issues, just change path to whatever can be easily located for you to save the .txt files)

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import os

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 8)


def center(win):
    """
    centers a tkinter window
    param win: the window to center on the screen
    """
    win.update_idletasks()
    width = win.winfo_width()
    frm_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    win_width = width + 2 * frm_width
    height = win.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
    win_height = height + titlebar_height + frm_width
    x = win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - win_width // 2
    y = win.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - win_height // 2
    win.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    win.deiconify()


def popupmsg(msg):
    popup1 = tk.Tk()
    center(popup1)
    popup1.minsize(width=60, height=70)
    popup1.maxsize(width=60, height=70)
    popup1.wm_title("Attention!")
    label = ttk.Label(popup1, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT, anchor="center")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    b1 = ttk.Button(popup1, text="Ok", command=lambda: popup1.destroy())
    b1.pack()
    popup1.mainloop()


class Testapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="testappicon2.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Psychoacoustic Tests")

        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: self.destroy())
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Startpage, TestSelect, Test1):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            self.minsize(width=900, height=500)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Startpage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Startpage(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.titlelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="User Information", font = LARGE_FONT)
        self.titlelabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.firstnamelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="First Name: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.firstnamelabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.lastnamelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Last Name: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.lastnamelabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.firstnameentry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.firstnameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, sticky = 'we', columnspan = 3)
        self.lastnameentry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.lastnameentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, sticky = 'we', columnspan = 3)

        self.birthdaylabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Birthday: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.birthdaylabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.daydropdown = ttk.Combobox(self, justify='center', height=20, width=2,
                                   values = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
                                             15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
                                             26,27,28,29,30,31),
                                   state='readonly')
        self.daydropdown.grid(row=3, column=1, padx = 3, sticky = 'ew')

        self.monthdropdown = ttk.Combobox(self, justify='center', height=12, width=10,
                                     values = ('January','Feburary','March',
                                               'April','May','June','July',
                                               'August','September','October',
                                               'November','December'),
                                     state='readonly')
        self.monthdropdown.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=3, sticky = 'ew')            

        self.yeardropdown = ttk.Combobox(self, justify='center', height=20, width=4,
                                    values = (1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984,
                                              1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989,
                                              1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994,
                                              1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999),
                                    state = 'readonly')
        self.yeardropdown.grid(row=3, column=3, padx = 3, sticky = 'ew')

        self.genderlabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Gender: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.genderlabel.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.var = tk.IntVar()

        self.Maleradio = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Male', variable=self.var, value = 1)
        self.Maleradio.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky = 'w')

        self.Femaleradio = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Female', variable=self.var, value = 2)
        self.Femaleradio.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky = 'w')

        self.emaillabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Email: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.emaillabel.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.emailentry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.emailentry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

        self.experiencelabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Musical Experience: ", font = NORM_FONT)
        self.experiencelabel.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky = 'w', padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.expdropdown = ttk.Combobox(self, justify='center', height=3, width=17,
                                   values = ('No experience', 'Some experience',
                                             'Musician level'), state='readonly')
        self.expdropdown.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky = 'w')

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="To Tests", command= lambda: self.checkempty())
        self.button1.grid(row=8, column=3)


        def shortcut():
            controller.show_frame(TestSelect)

        buttonshort = ttk.Button(self, text="To Tests shortcut", command= lambda: shortcut())
        buttonshort.grid(row=9, column=3)


    def get_info(self):
        Name = self.firstnameentry.get()
        Surname = self.lastnameentry.get()
        Day = self.daydropdown.get()
        Month = self.monthdropdown.get()
        Year = self.yeardropdown.get()
        foldername = (str(Name[0]) + str(Surname[0]) +
                      str(Day) + "_" + str(Month) + "_" +
                      str(Year))
        return foldername

    def create_directory(self):
        if not os.path.isdir(self.get_info()):
            directory = "C:\Users\Rylan\Documents\Python\Basel Summerintern files\{}".format(self.get_info())
            os.makedirs(directory)
            datafile = "{}_userinfo.txt".format(self.get_info())
            entirefile = os.path.join(directory, datafile)
            myfile = open(entirefile, 'w')
            myfile.write(self.userinfo())
            myfile.close()
            self.controller.show_frame(TestSelect)
        else:
            popupmsg("Folder already exists")

    def userinfo(self):
        Name = self.firstnameentry.get()
        Surname = self.lastnameentry.get()
        Day = self.daydropdown.get()
        Month = self.monthdropdown.get()
        Year = self.yeardropdown.get()
        Email = self.emailentry.get()
        Experience = self.expdropdown.get()
        def genderget():
            Gender = self.var.get()
            if Gender == 1:
                UserGender = "Male"
            elif Gender == 2:
                UserGender = "Female"
            return UserGender
        user_info = ("Participant Name: " + str(Name) + " " +
                     str(Surname) + "\nBirthday: " + str(Day) + "_" +
                     str(Month) + "_" + str(Year) + "\nGender: " +
                     str(genderget()) + "\nEmail: " + str(Email) +
                     "\nMusical Experience: " + str(Experience) +
                     "\nDirectory Name: " + str(self.get_info()))
        return user_info

    def checkempty(self):
        Name = self.firstnameentry.get()
        Surname = self.lastnameentry.get()
        Day = self.daydropdown.get()
        Month = self.monthdropdown.get()
        Year = self.yeardropdown.get()
        Email = self.emailentry.get()
        Experience = self.expdropdown.get()
        if len(Name) == 0:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif len(Surname) == 0:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif Day == None:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif Month == None:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif Year == None:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif self.var.get() == 0:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif len(Email) == 0:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        elif Experience == None:
            popupmsg("Please complete the user information form")
        else:
            self.create_directory()


class TestSelect(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Select tests", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        Test1Button = ttk.Button(self, text="Do test 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Test1))
        Test1Button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx = 20, pady = 15, sticky = 'nsew')

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Startpage))
        button2.grid(row=3, column=2)


class Test1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Test 1", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page one", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestSelect))
        button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = "w")

        yesbutt1 = ttk.Button(self)
        yesbutt1.grid(row=2, column=0)
        nobutt1 = ttk.Button(self)
        nobutt1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        yesbutt1['text'] = "Yes: 0"
        nobutt1['text'] = "No: 0"
        self.nobttn_clicks = 0
        self.yesbttn_clicks = 0

        def update_countyes():
            if self.yesbttn_clicks >= 1 or self.nobttn_clicks >= 1:
                popupmsg("Only one answer allowed!")
            else:
                self.yesbttn_clicks += 1
                yesbutt1['text'] = "Yes: " + str(self.yesbttn_clicks)
                directory = "C:\Users\Rylan\Documents\Python\Basel Summerintern files\{}".format(self.get_t_info())
                datafile = "{}_test1data.txt".format(self.get_t_info())
                entirefile = os.path.join(directory, datafile)
                myfile = open(entirefile, 'a')
                myfile.write('\nyes')
                myfile.close()

        def update_countno():
            if self.yesbttn_clicks >= 1 or self.nobttn_clicks >= 1:
                popupmsg("Only one answer allowed!")
            else:
                self.nobttn_clicks += 1
                nobutt1['text'] = "No: " + str(self.nobttn_clicks)
                directory = "C:\Users\Rylan\Documents\Python\Basel Summerintern files\{}".format(self.get_t_info())
                datafile = "{}_test1data.txt".format(self.get_t_info())
                entirefile = os.path.join(directory, datafile)
                myfile = open(entirefile, 'a')
                myfile.write('\nno')
                myfile.close()

        yesbutt1['command'] = update_countyes
        nobutt1['command'] = update_countno

    def get_t_info(self):
        self.gettheinfo = Startpage(app, self.controller).get_info()
        return self.gettheinfo

app = Testapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you write:

```
def get_t_info(self):
    self.gettheinfo = Startpage(app, self.controller).get_info()
    return self.gettheinfo
```

you create a new StartPage where the Entries are empty.
Then

```
    Name = self.firstnameentry.get()
    ...
    foldername = (str(Name[0])
```

tries to get the first character of an empty string.

I think the solution should be something like:

```
def get_t_info(self):
    return self.controller.frames[Startpage]
```

Comment: Ah it works! Brilliant, thank you man! Just one simple line :)

Comment: 'def get_t_info(self):'
                'self.gettheinfo = self.controller.frames[Startpage].get_info()'
                'return self.gettheinfo' @Eric Levieil